# Laravel can't submit to database because too few arguments to function

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to pass an id when submitting to a database but I'm getting an error. When a user submits a review for a product I need the id to be saved. I can successfully add the review with hard coded values but when the page refreshes it throws an error:

"Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\PagesController::addreview(), 1 passed in /Users/stef/Desktop/GitHub/Nue/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php on line 54 and exactly 2 expected".

shows the product where user can add product to cart and/or submit a review
**show.blade.php**

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@addreview', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::post('/addreview', 'App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@addreview');
```

saves review to database then redirects back to the product page
**pagescontroller.php**

```
    public function addreview(Request $request, $id)
    {

        $this->validate($request, [

            'description' => 'required',
            'rating' => 'nullable',
        ]);

        $review =  new Review;

        $review->rating = $request->input('rating');
        $review->reviewerid = auth()->user()->id;
        $review->productid = $id;
        $review->description = $request->input('description');

        $review->save();

        return redirect('/products/{$id}')->with('success', 'Review submitted');
    }
```

Comment: Your route is defined as `/addreview` which doesn't list any parameters, but your action is defined as `addreview(Request $request, $id)` which says it expects a parameter called `$id`. Either, change your web route and form, or change your action's signature. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use like below code

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => ['App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@addreview', $product->id],'method' => 'POST']) !!}
```

and your route should be like below

```
Route::post('/addreview/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\PagesController@addreview');
```

[Follow this instruction](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/6.x/html)

Comment: had to change some code in some other places but it looks like its workin so far. Thanks!!

Comment: @stephanlewis, According to my solution, it works fine for you or solves your problem?

Comment: both. i can now submit to the database and have it redirect to the page without error

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped you.